# I plan to use the <time> tag in a php for loop - Unknown parameters for datetime

Tags: php, html

I have a forloop which is going to print announcements for me. I want to use the time tag and have come accross the datetime attribute. Because it is in a loop, I can't use a specific date, and I don't want to use a variable (for uk format reasons)... my question is, is there a specifier where teh precise date is not needed? Such as

```
<time datetime="YYYY-MM-DD">February 17, 2012</time>
```

Thanks in advance and sorry if this is a silly question

Comment: Why do you want to use a time tag?

Comment: What exactly is your question and where does your current attempt fail you?

Comment: This attribute is for specific date that reflects tag contents, but in standardized format. In your example, it should be `2012-02-17`.

Comment: @kingkero in the datetime="****/**/**" what can I put there if the date is unknown

Comment: The `datetime` attribute is used to specify the timestamp in a universal way, while the contents of the `time` tag are what's going to be shown. All you need to know is written [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/time) and maybe a little bit easier to read (although w3schools are known for having mistakes on their website) [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_time.asp). You can follow the `datetime` links on either links to get details on the format of the datetime attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no valid way to use the [`time`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-time-element) element for something that is not a specific date or time. That would be against its very definition.

On the other hand, there is no known support to the `time` element in browsers or search engines (beyond the point that browsers just parse the element and insert it to the DOM). It’s in practice so far just an element that you can process in JavaScript (or style with CSS). So when this element is not even in principle adequate, use some other element, like `span` (with an attribute like `data-date` if you like – you can then use whatever values you need for it).

Answer (score 0):

In your loop, you need to output *both* the machine-readable date in the `datetime` attribute and the human-readable date in the content of the tag, like this:

```
$timestamps = array(1329472800, 1388916000);

foreach ($timestamps as $ts) {
    echo strftime("<time datetime='%F'>%B %e, %Y</time>\n", $ts);
}
```

which [will output](http://ideone.com/SW3CHg):

```
<time datetime='2012-02-17'>February 17, 2012</time>
<time datetime='2014-01-05'>January  5, 2014</time>
```

(I'm using [strftime()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) instead of [date()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) because the strftime() format syntax is easier to embed in HTML.)

---

If you only have the dates as text, you may be able to parse them with [strtotime()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php), like this:

```
$dates = array("February 17, 2012", "First Sunday of 2014", "Whatever");

foreach ($dates as $date) {
    $ts = strtotime($date);
    $date_html = htmlspecialchars($date);
    if ($ts) {
        $iso_date = strftime("%F", $ts);
        echo "<time datetime='$iso_date'>$date_html</time>\n";
    } else {
        echo "<span class='error'>Invalid date: $date_html</span>\n";
    }
}
```

which [will output](http://ideone.com/cIeX5e):

```
<time datetime='2012-02-17'>February 17, 2012</time>
<time datetime='2014-01-05'>First Sunday of 2014</time>
<span class='error'>Invalid date: Whatever</span>
```

Be careful, though: strtotime() is pretty good at parsing dates in random formats, but its behavior is not always easy to predict.  For example, while testing the code above, I was quite surprised to find out that it apparently accepts the input `"I dunno"` and interprets it as "7 hours ago"(!).  I dunno why.